# Типы лексических значений

Tags: значение-слов, лексикография, лексика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, пишу работу по статье Виноградова "Типы лексических значений".

Первый тип — прямое, или номинативное значение. Это лексическое значение слова непосредственно связано с отражением явлений объективной реальности. Действительно, помимо нашего сознания и независимо от его, то есть объективно, нас окружают предметы реальной действительности. Те слова, которые связаны с отражением действительности, обладают прямым лексическим значением. Такие слова свободно сочетаются с другими словами. Вот почему прямое, номинативное значение называют также свободным, то есть слова, имеющие прямое, номинативное значение, не ограничиваются в своем употреблении определенными речевыми и фразеологическими оборотами: они имеют широкие словесные связи.

То есть слова, которые относятся к первому типу, это слова употребленные просто в прямом лексическом значении??? Так?

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, просто в прямом значении (золотые (рудники), золотые слитки, золотые монеты), а в переносном будет другой тип - фразеологически связанный (золотые руки, золотая свадьба, золотая пора), а синтаксически связанное значение - "ты у нас золото". Сущ. выполняет роль подлежащего или дополнения, а вот "золото" как сказуемое - синтаксически обусловленное значение.

Comment: спасибо большущее !!!